# How can I create admin user accounts that can register non-admin user accounts in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm creating an application in which I need to have two different login routes. One of them would be an admin log-in where only admin accounts can log in.

Once an admin is logged in, he can register new "normal" users (these users will represent hotels, and will be associated with a database table that stores hotel info), which will be able to log-in through the normal log-in route.

In short, only admin users can register non-admin users, and non-admin users can log-in but can't register.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at writing any code or solution for this scenario yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not good to be honest , so this answer will be just a hint

you dont need 2 routes for login as you mentioned , you need to setup for the `users` : `roles` and `permission`

You can start doing thins by checking this [Package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

You can find a lot about this on the internet, you have to start coding first then if you had any kind of problemes you can ask a question here.

-you will not have a register page , but you will have a create user page, but only a user with a role of admin that have a permission of creating users can access it

you can define other roles and permissions too as you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can create two routes, for example:

- `login` to normal users
- `admin/login` admin users

Then in your login controller you should verify the user's role if admin or normal user to success login.

But you should add a admin user directly in the database because cannot register from the web.